# Change encoding on Azure queue message with version 12.x of Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I have moved from v11 to v12 of the Azure library.
When I insert a message using the following code:

```
        private static void insertQueueMessage(string messageToInsert, string queueName)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString")); //points to the azure storage account

        // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue for our new files to be imported to LOB
        CloudQueue incomingCustomerQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);
        CloudQueueMessage newQueueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(messageToInsert);

        incomingCustomerQueue.AddMessage(newQueueMessage);
    }
```

That inserts it as a base 64 encoded message

When I try and retrieve it using a normal Console app (also using the 12.x library)
with the following code:

```
            QueueClient queue = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);
        
        // process each of the messages
        foreach (QueueMessage jsonMessage in queue.ReceiveMessages(maxMessages: 10).Value)
        {
            //decode message
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {jsonMessage.Body}");
            incomingMessageInfo messageData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<incomingMessageInfo>(jsonMessage.Body.ToString());
```

it fails due to the message being encoded.
If I manually using Azure Explorer change the encoding to be UTF-8, it works.

I have found some references to "specify the MessageEncoding when injecting the service"
I do not know how to do this.

This is a normal C# Console application targeting .NET 4.8

Update From Answer - trying to apply a new instance of queue options:

```
  // Create the queue client.
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        QueueClientOptions newOptions = new QueueClientOptions();
        newOptions.MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.None;

        // Retrieve a reference to a queue for our new files to be imported to LOB
        CloudQueue incomingCustomerQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);
        CloudQueueMessage newQueueMessage = new CloudQueueMessage(messageToInsert);

        incomingCustomerQueue.AddMessage(newQueueMessage);
```

Final Code that fixed it:

```
            QueueClientOptions newOptions = new QueueClientOptions();
        newOptions.MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.None;
        QueueClient qcl = new QueueClient(conString, queueName, newOptions);
        var response = qcl.SendMessage(messageToInsert);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are looking for is [`MessageEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclientoptions.messageencoding?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-queues-queueclientoptions-messageencoding) property which is available in [`QueueClientOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet) class.

You would need to create a new instance of `QueueClientOptions` and set its `MessageEncoding` property to `QueueMessageEncoding.None`. You will then need to use this option when creating an instance of [`QueueServiceClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueserviceclient?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: There is no .EncodeMessage available for version 12 forward.  that is from Package:
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Queue v11.1.0.  But thank you for the response.

Comment: Updated my answer for the latest SDK. HTH.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that exactly.  I will update my question to show what I have so far from your answer.....thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe you are mixing v11 and v12. AFAIK, v12 does not have `CloudQueueClient`. It has `QueueServiceClient`.

Comment: Oh my...you are correct!  Very sorry, I was updating a very old project and did not realize I misspelled the routine call.   Updating and testing now.